# Hibernate JPA UniDirectional OneToOne Join - Updating a null foreign key after been inserted as null

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to achieve the following scenario using a uni-directional OneToOne mapping using JPA Hibernate in a Spring-Boot Web Application:

1. Use ***CrudRepository.save()*** to insert a record in an entity
   (EntityTwo) with the foreign key of another entity (EntityOne) as null
2. Update the inserted
   record to set the foreign key to a not null value using ***CrudRepository.save()***

Entity One looks like this:

```java
@Entity
public class EntityOne implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "entity_one_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

}
```

Entity Two looks like this:

```java
@Entity
public class EntityTwo implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_one_id")
    private EntityOne entityOne;
}
```

So here's what save calls look like

First save call:

```java
EntityTwo entityTwo = new EntityTwo();
entityTwoRepository.save(entityTwo);
```

Second save call:

```java
EntityOne entityOne = entityOneRepository.getByEntityOneId(1); // this results in a not-null value
EntityTwo entityTwo = new EntityTwo();
entityTwo.setEntityOne(entityOne);
entityTwoRepository.save(entityTwo);
```

After the second call, my hope is that the foreign key will be set in EntityTwo but its not the case. Please let me know if I am doing something completely wrong or if there is a better / other way to achieve this using Spring-Boot JPA

Answer (score 0):

You should cascade operations.

```
@Entity
public class EntityOne implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "entity_one_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

}

@Entity
public class EntityTwo implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_one_id")
    private EntityOne entityOne;
}
```

Try;

```
EntityOne entityOne = new EntityOne();
EntityTwp entityTwo = new EntityTwo();
entityTow.setEntityOne(entityOne);
entityTwoRepository.save(entityTwo);
```